# Deserializing a serialized table or rectangularifying a list of text lines

Tags: csv, pdf, text, command-line, transformation

Sometimes I have text tables not in the normal form column next to column, but column *after* column, i.e.  all columns of the table are listed after each other on individual text lines. (This, for example, happens when you copy-paste a table from a PDF table.)

Here an example. The proper table looks like this:

```
Date        |  From - To              |  Flight   |  Departs Arrives        
------------|-------------------------|-----------|-------------------------
29-Jun-17   |  Sydney - Beijing       |  EK174    |  19:40 05:30 (30-Jun-17)
05-Jul-17   |  Beijing - Frankfurt    |  EK931    |  14:00 18:15            
12-Aug-17   |  Frankfurt - Shanghai   |  EK736    |  20:00 13:05 (13-Aug-17)
13-Aug-17   |  Shanghai - Sydney      |  EK175    |  19:35 08:10 (14-Aug-17)
```

However I have the data in the following lines:

```
Date
29-Jun-17 
05-Jul-17 
12-Aug-17 
13-Aug-17
From - To
Sydney - Beijing 
Beijing - Frankfurt 
Frankfurt - Shanghai 
Shanghai - Sydney
Flight 
EK174 
EK931 
EK736 
EK175
Departs Arrives
19:40 05:30 (30-Jun-17)
14:00 18:15 
20:00 13:05 (13-Aug-17)
19:35 08:10 (14-Aug-17)
```

My question: ***Is there a command line tool to convert this list of columns into the before mentioned table it obviously resembles?*** The (unix-based or else) tool would obviously need some help to cut the list into columns by, say, a parameter how many rows each column has or something similar.

Also, this appears to me as a *transformation problem*. Is this known under some specify term (so that it is easier to find a tool with an Internet search for that term)? - I call it *ad hoc* something like "**rectangularifying a list**" or "**deserialising a serialised table**"...

Comment: are they always go in such order `Date ... From/to ... Flight ... Departs Arrives ...` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Short answer: Yes! Long answer: The text table does not come in the normal form column *next* to column, but column *after* column. - I will update the question to make this clearer.

Comment: what's your OS? I can suggest "unix-based" solution

Comment: Unix-based is what I was looking for (I'm on macOS and Windows with bash tools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that apparently no standard solution through a pre-implemented text-transformation exists, here a version to do it in Python. The input is given in the file `series.txt`, the output is written to `table.txt`, the number of rows in each column hard coded for this example as `row_num = 5`:

```
import csv

with open('series.txt', 'r') as inpfile:
    lines = inpfile.read().splitlines()
row_num = 5
# distribute to columns
cols = []
idx = 0
for l in lines:
    if idx == 0:
        cols.append([])
        idx = row_num

    cols[-1].append(l)
    idx -= 1;
# output columns
with open('table.txt', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for idx in range(0,row_num):
        out = ['{:<25}'.format(col[idx]) for col in cols]
        csvwriter.writerow(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `awk`(`gawk`) + `pr` approach:
At first, we'll split the input file into 5 separate files(each one for a separate pattern):

```
awk '/Date|From - To|Flight|Departs Arrives/{gsub(/^ +| +$/, "", $0);fn=gensub(/[ -]+/, "-","g",$0); 
print $0 > "/tmp/"fn; next}{print > "/tmp/"fn;}' testfile
```

The above command will split the input file `testfile` into multiple files at every occurrence of each of the specified patterns `/Date|From - To|Flight|Departs Arrives/`

`$0` - points to a *header*(containing column name) line(e.g. `Date`)

`gsub(/^ +| +$/, "", $0);` - will strip all trailing spaces from each *header* line (e.g. "Flight  ")

`fn=gensub(/[ -]+/, "-","g",$0);` - replacing multiple spaces/dashes with a single dash to get a more suitable file name. `fn` variable is assigned with a file name

`print $0 > "/tmp/"fn;` - will print a *header/pattern* line into respective file(e.g. `Date` line will be written into `/tmp/Date` file)

`print > "/tmp/"fn;` - writing all subsequent records to the respective file till the next pattern comes.

Eventually, we'll obtain the following files: 
`/tmp/Date`, `/tmp/From-To`, `/tmp/Flight`, `/tmp/Departs-Arrives`

---

Now, we can merge and format our files to print them columnwise using `pr` command:

```
pr -t -m -w 100 -s"|" /tmp/Date /tmp/From-To /tmp/Flight /tmp/Departs-Arrives
```

The output:

```
Date            |From - To               |Flight          |Departs Arrives
29-Jun-17       |Sydney - Beijing        |EK174           |19:40 05:30 (30-Jun-17)
05-Jul-17       |Beijing - Frankfurt     |EK931           |14:00 18:15
12-Aug-17       |Frankfurt - Shanghai    |EK736           |20:00 13:05 (13-Aug-17)
13-Aug-17       |Shanghai - Sydney       |EK175           |19:35 08:10 (14-Aug-17)
```

To learn more abount `pr` command: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/pr.htm

Comment: Thanks! Certainly works. Feels a bit complicated though. I was *hoping* that this problem has (apart from the pretty-printing) a standard solution  through some pre-implemented "transformation"...